# Dynamic For Comprehensions

Tags: scala

I'm relatively new to Scala so I'm not super confident with the language and I need your help to solve a problem. I know that the for-comprehension is just a syntactic sugar to simplify complex map/flatMap hierarchies.

Now, consider to have 3 different Range intervals, which should be combined in order to create all the possible combinations (respecting the intervals) of values.

**Example**:

Using the for-comprehension the problem can be solved as:

```
val intervalX = 1 to 5
val intervalY = 6 to 13
val intervalZ = 20 to 50
for {
  x <- intervalX;
  y <- intervalY;
  z <- intervalZ
} yield (x,y,z)
```

Which is converted by the Scala compiler as:

```
intervalX.flatMap{x =>
    intervalY.flatMap{y =>
        intervalZ.map{z => (x,y,z)}
    }
}
```

However, the problem is harder if you are given in input a **variable** number d of intervals. Is it possible to perform the same operation, obtaining all the possible d-tuples? I think that it could be solved using the foldLeft operation, but I am not able to write it correctly at the moment. Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: With a lots of boilerplate it is possible, but I would suggest using a library helping to reduce that boilerplate as much as possible, I think shapeless is ideal for that. (Also note that tuples are supported till 22, so `d` should be `<=22`.)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know this library. Can you give me an hint with respect to which functionality should I study?

Comment: If the input is an `HList` of `Range`s for example, the result can be an `HList` of the combinations. Also the [`shapeless.syntax.std.tuple`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples) part might be even closer to your expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live without tuples as a result then a version using foldLeft and returning lists representing combinations could be:

```
val intervalX = 1 to 5
val intervalY = 6 to 13
val intervalZ = 20 to 50
val ranges = intervalZ :: intervalY :: intervalX :: Nil
val combos = ranges.foldLeft(Iterable[Seq[Int]](Nil)) { case (c, e) =>
   for {
      i <- e
      j <- c
   } yield i +: j
}
combos foreach { println(_) }
```